# ¿Cómo asignar valores a un arreglo de un objeto?

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes comunidad,

Tengo una clase con sus propiedades, entre ellas, hay una que es un arreglo de otro objeto.

```
public class encabezado
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public detalle[] detalles;
}

public class detalle
{
    public double saldo1 {get;set;}
    public double saldo2 {get;set;}
}
```

estoy tratando de asignar valores a detalle directamente, así:

```
encabezado encabezado = new encabezado();
encabezado.ID = 1;
encabezado.nombre = Alex;
encabezado.detalle[0].saldo1 = 5.4;
encabezado.detalle[0].saldo2 = 6.6;
encabezado.detalle[1].saldo1 = 5.4;
encabezado.detalle[1].saldo2 = 6.6;
```

sin embargo, al hacer esto, me arroja el error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error que surge es porque no se instancia el arreglo y ademas no se define un tamaño del arreglo.

Realice algunas modificaciones en tu código espero te sirva esta solución:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        encabezado en = new encabezado();
        en.ID = 1;
        en.nombre = "Alex";
//Cree una nueva instancia de la clase detalle y la asigne al arreglo detalles en la posicion [0]
        detalle dt = new detalle();
        dt.saldo1 = 3.3;
        dt.saldo2 = 5.4;
        en.detalles[0] = dt;

        Console.WriteLine(en.ID + " " + en.nombre + " " + en.detalles[0].saldo1 + "  " + en.detalles[0].saldo2);
    }
}

public class encabezado
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string nombre { get; set; }
//Inicialize el arreglo con un tamaño de 2
    public detalle[] detalles = new detalle[2];
}

public class detalle
{
    public double saldo1 {get;set;}
    public double saldo2 {get;set;}
}
```

Cualquier duda estoy al pendiente. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

De la misma forma en que creaste una nueva instancia de la clase encabezado:

```
 encabezado encabezado = new encabezado();
```

También debes crear una nueva instancia del arreglo de clases detalle:

```
 encabezado.detalle = new detalle[1];
```

Para que entonces puedas continuar con tu código:

```
encabezado.ID = 1;
encabezado.nombre = Alex;
encabezado.detalle[0].saldo1 = 5.4;
encabezado.detalle[0].saldo2 = 6.6;
encabezado.detalle[1].saldo1 = 5.4;
encabezado.detalle[1].saldo2 = 6.6;
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Te cuento que intenté esto, pero me sigue tirando la misma excepción.